# Get size of Window before Show()

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to use the `Width` and `Height` properties of a `Window` to determine where on the screen it should be displayed.

Of course these aren't available until you actually draw the Window (via the `Window.Show()` method).

Now my current hack/workaround is to set the `Top` and `Left` properties to `-9999`, `Show()` and then reposition.

I am wondering if there is a non hacky way of doing this?

(On a side note, having looked at the documentation, I should probably be using the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Loaded event of the target Window. In the handler, both the ActualWidth/ActualHeight and Width/Height are valid.

```
Window wnd; //...
wnd.Loaded += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
{
    // Set wnd.Top and wnd.Left here.
};
wnd.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly but is worth a shot;

> Set Window's opacity property to 0% then show the Window and calculate the dimensions.

Comment: That is still a "hack" though.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you actually try to do, you can use the layout system:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

For example you could override MeasureOverride or ArrangeOverride to detect new size during layouting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing something here. You can just set the Location and Size properties in the IDE. You can also set them programmatically before Show().

Comment: I wish to set the location based on the rendered size. The Size is set to `Auto` which means its determined by its contents